# Issue with nested for loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm working on a project in Excel that helps a club here on campus allocate money to various other clubs. Anyways, I'm attempting to implement a macro-assigned button to allow the club to generate a new sheet that summarizes the event name, and the funding granted to the event.

The issue I'm currently stuck on is assigning 12 rows of data on this new sheet, for each club listed in the 'Summary' tab. I have the formula so that it cycles through the summary tab and inputs the club name down, but it continually inputs these names into cells A1-A12, rather than adding 12 new rows for the next club.

If my wording is confusing to follow; I want club 1's data to be in cells A1-12, club 2 in A13-24, etc.

I'm relying on nested for loops to try and cycle through and create these rows. Here's the part that's giving me trouble:

```
     For k = 0 To 200 Step 12

       'J is used to get names off the 'summary' tab
        For j = 8 To Sheets.Count

               'I is used to select cells 'a1' to 'a12'
                For i = 1 To 12

                    Range("A" & (k + i)).Select
                    ActiveCell.Formula = ("=Summary!$A$" & j)
             Next i
             Next j
             Next k
```

I'm certain my problem lies in the fact that j is advanced further before k, meaning it will continue to see k as 0 and input the new club's name in a1-a12, rather than stepping it up 12 BEFORE j is advanced. Whenever I try to insert next k above next j, I'm given an error.

This nested for loop is messy and is starting to make my brain hurt- but I can't seem to figure out a better way to tell Excel to skip 12 rows at a time. If anyone has any input or ideas on how to execute this macro in an easier way- let me know :-)

Comment: have you tried adding a break point and stepping through your code to see how it is adding things to the worksheet?

Comment: @R.Roe Yes! It adds the club name (from the reference to the Summary tab) just fine. Going through only the inner for loop once gives me cells a1-a12 filled with the first club's name. It is telling the macro to then start at cell a13 to start adding club 2's data where I'm having issues. Hope that answered what you were asking.

Comment: So when you step through your code it works for the first iteration but breaks for the second.  When it gets to that point is where the stepping through the code is essential.  Ask yourself which ranges is it referencing, and which cells is it copying to.  If you do that you will find your issue.  To me the loops look good, but it's all about context.  There isn't enough information to tell why it's breaking.

Comment: Right, I have been doing that and came to the conclusion I had mentioned in my OP. 

I'm certain my problem lies in the fact that j is advanced further before k, meaning it will continue to see k as 0 and input the new club's name in a1-a12, rather than stepping it up 12 BEFORE j is advanced.

Is there anyway you may know of to 'step-out' of the J Loop to advance K, then step back into the J Loop to populate the next 12 cells with the correct club name?

Comment: `Exit For` is how you step out of a for loop, but you can't step back in.  Have you tried rearranging your loops?

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the input. So, would you say that approaching this with nested for loops isn't the best idea?

Comment: There are many ways to do things.  Looping through ranges is a good solution, but you can also store your information in an array, a dictionary object, or a collection, and call the information later.  I like to store ranges in variant declarations and loop through the variant object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. There is no need to select cell before writing formula in it...

```
For j = 8 To Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To 12
       Range("A" & ((j - 8) * 12 + i)).Formula = ("=Summary!$A$" & j)
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: Kresimir! Thank you my friend! I saw you post something earlier and remove it, so I do appreciate you investing so much time into my problem. You rock!